# Android ajax Query Async API callback not firing

Tags: android, ajax, callback

I have this code from Android Query Async API sample, but the callback is never called.

```
 public void asyncJson(){          
    String url = "http://www.mysite.com/MyService.asmx/GetJson";

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("100", "Param1");

    aq.ajax(url, params, JSONObject.class, new AjaxCallback<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void callback(String url, JSONObject json, AjaxStatus status) {

            int dummy=0; // breakpoint here....but it never stops the debugger here
            //showResult(json);               
        }
    });

 } // asyncJson
```

I have put a breakpoint on int dummy=0 and it never stops there. The ajax line is executed correctly, also there are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

After changed the params.put("100", "Param1"); to params.put("Param1", "100"); the callback was called.